# C# Async method usage

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, async-await

I am trying to use Aync method. It's working in a way. But it's not working in some other context.

Working example

```
dropBox.DownloadFileAsync(csvEntry.Path)
                    .ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        // Save file to "C:\Spring Social.txt"
                        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(tempCsvPath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            fileStream.Write(task.Result.Content, 0, task.Result.Content.Length);
                        }
                    });
```

Instead of saving the file, I am trying to return the byte array in the following way. But it's not working. It is returning null.

```
 byte[] returnArray = null;
                dropbox.DownloadFileAsync(filePath)
                        .ContinueWith(task =>
                        {
                            returnArray = new byte[task.Result.Content.Length];
                            task.Result.Content.CopyTo(returnArray, 0);
                        });
                return returnArray;
```

Can somebody correct me?

Thanks

Comment: Surely DownloadFileAsync is asynchronous, and so therefore you should not expect it to have completed by the time you hit the next statement (your "return" statement)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

```
            byte[] returnArray = null;
            dropbox.DownloadFileAsync(filePath)
                    .ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        returnArray = new byte[task.Result.Content.Length];
                        task.Result.Content.CopyTo(returnArray, 0);
                    });
            return returnArray;
```

DownloadFileAsync() is executed on a thread. When the ContinueWith() is executed your function that calls DowloadFileAsync() already has returned.

You would need to do something like this:

```
     Task<T> Download(string filePath)
     {             
            return dropbox.DownloadFileAsync(filePath)
                    .ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        returnArray = new byte[task.Result.Content.Length];
                        task.Result.Content.CopyTo(returnArray, 0);

                        return returnArray;
                    });
      }
```

Call it like this:

```
     var task = Download("myfile");

     task.ContinueWith(t => 
      { 
           var returnArray = t.Result;
           ...

      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed my code as you mentioned and I am relying on task.Result where task is returned by Download method. Is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: It's not “executed on a background thread”. A big point of using `async` is that it doesn't block any thread when doing IO.

Comment: it's still a thread where the async code is executed, or not?

Comment: **It's not “executed on a background thread** -> it IS executed in the background, but when you say `something = t.result;` you BLOCK the current thread until the task is done. If you dont want that, use "await" (if you use VS2012 and target FW 4.x)

Comment: @igrimpe but the `something = t.result` is only executed in the continuation, so the thread (UI thread in this case I guess), where `Download()` is called, is not blocked, or not?

Comment: @pivotnig: since OP "relies on task.result" (as he commented) and complains that it does not run in the background, I assumed that he uses .Result in the main thread. OP: please update your question to show your ACTUAL source code.